# Is there anyway to constrain elements in Xcode to be the same distance apart in all views?

Tags: xcode, constraints

I have been trying to get my app to look good on all views. I have concluded that this setup might be the best way to do it. However, after playing with constraints, I can't seem to find a good solution.

[image: How does one design something like this]

There might be a way to do this programatically. However, I feel the constraints should be enough to make this happen. Has anybody tried something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your views have their sizes determined already (by `intrinsicContentSize`, or by explicit width and height constraints), I think you can achieve this effect by:

1. Constraining the middle view's `centerX` and `centerY` to equal the superview's `centerX` and `centerY`
2. Constraining the top and bottom views' `centerX` to both equal the middle view's `centerX`
3. Constraining the top and bottom views to have a fixed vertical space from the middle view

This should be possible both in Interface Builder and in code.

Have caution that your views don't get clipped in the smallest screen sizes, or in landscape orientation. If your views are resizable, you might add inequality constraints from the outer edges of the top and bottom views to the superview, so that they'll maintain some minimum space from the edge of the screen.